# My query with a subquery won't return an empty set

Tags: mysql, subquery

I have two tables in MySQL:

Table 1 - WORKORDERS

| ID | QUANTITY |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 1 |

Table 2 - ITEMSINWORKORDERS

| ID | WORKORDER |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 |

I have a query:

```
SELECT WORKORDERS.ID
      , WORKORDERS.QUANTITY AS NOMINAL_QTY
      , COUNT(ITEMSINWORKORDERS.WORKORDER) AS ENTERED_QTY
FROM  WORKORDERS JOIN ITEMSINWORKORDERS ON
         ITEMSINWORKORDERS.WORKORDER = WORKORDERS.ID
WHERE WORKORDERS.QUANTITY >
        ( SELECT COUNT(ITEMSINWORKORDERS.WORKORDER )
          FROM   WORKORDERS INNER JOIN ITEMSINWORKORDERS ON
                    ITEMSINWORKORDERS.WORKORDER = WORKORDERS.ID
        )
```

Originally, I had a [left outer join](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)#Left_outer_join) in my statement, so I switched it to inner in hopes of getting an empty set.  How can I make it return an empty set whenever there aren't any work orders with missing entries?

Which is intended to find all work orders where not all items have been entered, and the nominal quantity, entered in the WORKORDERS table is greater than the number of records in ITEMSINWORKORDERS corresponding to that work order.  I expected to return an *empty set*.  Instead, I get

| ID | NOMINAL_QTY | ENTERED_QTY |
| --- | --- | --- |
| NULL | NULL | 0 |

Originally, I had a left outer join in my statement, so I switched it to inner in hopes of getting an empty set.

*Addendum:*
I tried solving this myself using NULLIF  thus:

```
SELECT WORKORDERS.ID
    , WORKORDERS.QUANTITY AS NOMINAL_QTY
    , NULLIF(COUNT(ITEMSINWORKORDERS.WORKORDER), 0) AS ENTERED_QTY
FROM WORKORDERS JOIN ITEMSINWORKORDERS ON
    ITEMSINWORKORDERS.WORKORDER = WORKORDERS.ID
WHERE WORKORDERS.QUANTITY >
    ( SELECT COUNT( ITEMSINWORKORDERS.WORKORDER )
    FROM WORKORDERS INNER JOIN ITEMSINWORKORDERS ON
        ITEMSINWORKORDERS.WORKORDER = WORKORDERS.ID
    )
```

What I got was frustrating:

| ID | NOMINAL_QTY | ENTERED_QTY |
| --- | --- | --- |
| NULL | NULL | NULL |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what you expoect as your qiery delivers no rows.

But for count to work you need a `GROUP BY`

> ```
> CREATE TABLE WORKORDERS (
>   `ID` INTEGER,
>   `QUANTITY` INTEGER
> );
>
> INSERT INTO WORKORDERS
>   (`ID`, `QUANTITY`)
> VALUES
>   ('1', '2'),
>   ('2', '1');
>
> CREATE TABLE ITEMSINWORKORDERS (
>   `ID` INTEGER,
>   `WORKORDER` INTEGER
> );
>
> INSERT INTO ITEMSINWORKORDERS
>   (`ID`, `WORKORDER`)
> VALUES
>   ('1', '1'),
>   ('2', '1'),
>   ('3', '2');
> ```

> ```
> SELECT WORKORDERS.ID
>       , WORKORDERS.QUANTITY AS NOMINAL_QTY
>       , COUNT(ITEMSINWORKORDERS.WORKORDER) AS ENTERED_QTY 
> FROM  WORKORDERS JOIN ITEMSINWORKORDERS ON 
>          ITEMSINWORKORDERS.WORKORDER = WORKORDERS.ID 
> WHERE WORKORDERS.QUANTITY > 
>         ( SELECT COUNT(ITEMSINWORKORDERS.WORKORDER ) 
>           FROM   WORKORDERS INNER JOIN ITEMSINWORKORDERS ON 
>                     ITEMSINWORKORDERS.WORKORDER = WORKORDERS.ID 
>         ) 
> GROUP BY WORKORDERS.ID
>       , WORKORDERS.QUANTITY
> ```
>
> ```
> ID | NOMINAL_QTY | ENTERED_QTY
> -: | ----------: | ----------:
> ```

> ```
> SELECT COUNT(ITEMSINWORKORDERS.WORKORDER ) 
>           FROM   WORKORDERS INNER JOIN ITEMSINWORKORDERS ON 
>                     ITEMSINWORKORDERS.WORKORDER = WORKORDERS.ID
> ```
>
> ```
> | COUNT(ITEMSINWORKORDERS.WORKORDER ) |
> | ----------------------------------: |
> |                                   3 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f3221d53e4352b157b658e2c704a0cf5)*